# Validation Group in Asp.Net MultiView

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have `multiView` and `Validation group` in my code. According to my code when user press button all the data in views needs to be saved.

```
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">    
     <asp:View ID="viewGegevens" runat="server">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyname" MaxLength="100" runat="server" CssClass=""></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ToolTip="Bedrijfsnaam vereist!"
                                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="Save" ControlToValidate="txtCompanyname"
                                CssClass="required-asterics"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

         <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave1" Text="Opslaan" runat="server" CssClass="btn-ctrl right" OnClick="txtSave1_Click" ValidationGroup="Save">Save
            </asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel1" Text="Annuleren" runat="server" CssClass="btn-ctrl right" OnClick="txtCancel1_Click">  Cancel 
            </asp:LinkButton>    
         </div>
      </asp:View>

      <asp:View ID="viewGegevens2" runat="server">
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtBillingPostalCode" runat="server" CssClass="" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ToolTip="Postcode vereist!"
                                ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="Save" ControlToValidate="txtBillingPostalCode"
                                Display="Dynamic" CssClass="required-asterics"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

         <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave2" Text="Opslaan" runat="server" CssClass="btn-ctrl right" OnClick="txtSave2_Click" ValidationGroup="Save">Save
            </asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="txtCancel2" Text="Annuleren" runat="server" CssClass="btn-ctrl right" OnClick="txtCancel2_Click">  Cancel 
            </asp:LinkButton>    
         </div>
      </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

My problem is i need to fire required field validation in both tabs either user press `btnSave1` or `btnSave2`.
But now if i press btnSave1 it only fires validations in 1st tab only. How can i solve this?

Comment: ASP.NET Multiview is designed to display one view at a time. If you inspect the html rendered at the client, you should not see the html of the 2nd view, do you?

Comment: @zed u r correct. then is that possible to add validation group to tab change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't do it like this out of the box.

ASP.NET Multiview is designed to display and validate one view at a time. So only the active view's html is delivered to the client's browser.

There is a [workaround](http://weblogs.asp.net/alnurismail/asp-net-validators-in-a-multiview) but may give you problems if you are using MultiView's ActiveViewChanged event.

Another option would be to refactor your page and use two divs, one for each step, making one or the other visible when changing from first to second step, and validate entire page once in the last step. This will require you to do more work with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround for this that works in my case.  I made the different views validate when the tabs are clicked in the code behind preventing the user from leaving the view without validating.

```
protected void Tab3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("YourValidationGroup");
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        Tab1.CssClass = "Initial";
        Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
        Tab3.CssClass = "Clicked";
        MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
    }
}
```

I know this in an old thread but figured I'd throw it out there for future people experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SelectView(0);
        Validate();
        if (IsValid)
        {
            SelectView(1);
            Validate();
            if (IsValid)
            {
                SelectView(2);
                Validate();
                if (IsValid)
                {
                    SelectView(3);
                    Validate();
                    if (IsValid)
                    {
                        UpdateHeader();
                        Response.Redirect("FinConfLanding.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```